# How to stop angularJs flickering screen

Tags: angularjs

I'm newbie on AngularJs. I made website with angularJS template.

Everything works fine but, after clicking and loading some page content, I got flickering screen problem. I have included angular.min.js in header.

How I can solve the flickering problem ?

HTML - HERE IS MY CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>MYAPP</title>

    <link href="stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/81204b271a.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-css.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>


   <style>
     [ng:cloak], 
     [ng-cloak], 
     [data-ng-cloak], 
     [x-ng-cloak], 
     .ng-cloak, 
     .x-ng-cloak {
        display: none !important;
     }
   </style>

  </head>

  <body ng-app="myapp" ng-cloak>
    <!-- VIEWS-->
    <div class="page {{ pageClass }}" ng-view=""></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script>
         new WOW().init();
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the best way will be to include the [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak), this will remove the flicker problem.

Comment: You are calling jquery twice it looks like. That may be related.

Comment: Yep, it's solved my problem. Thank u so much!

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for `ng-cloak`. I have used this and it has alleviated my issues with cloaking.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: i tried this but maybe i did it not correctly. I added the style in head "[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}" and add class to body like that but my problem is not solved   <body ng-app="myapp" ng-cloak class="{{ bodyClass }}"> .

Comment: Did you put it at where you place your ng-app in the html markup?

Comment: yes like <body ng-app="myapp" ng-cloak class="{{ bodyClass }}">

Comment: It may have to do with you using angular for css classes. It may be loading in slower and which is causing the flicker.

Comment: I would not try to alter the cloak css properties that may be there within angular. Maybe just run the app without a class on the body to see if this is what is causing your issue to occur.

Comment: <body ng-app="igoaimalathane" ng-cloak> i tried to use like that too, without class but nothing changed

Comment: Interesting, well to further help with your issue can you please post the code you have so far and we can further inspect what the issue may be! Cheers :)

Answer (score -1):

Add ng-cloak at the angular js root element(ag-app). This will display the view on screen only after the angular  complies the DOM elememts (Angular extended HTML attributes)

Comment: I added the code into my question. You can check?  because i think i add the ng-cloak to my root element